# Need help in formulating an SQL Query ( mysql )

Tags: mysql

I have this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `person` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `father` text NOT NULL,
  `mother` text NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;
```

and the data:

```
(`ID`, `father`, `mother`, `name`)
( 1       ''        ''     'Robert Darwin'),
( 2       ''        ''     'Josiah Wedgwood'),
( 3       ''        ''     'Sarah Wedgwood'),
( 4       ''        ''     'Mary Howard'),
( 5       1         ''     'Erasmus Darwin'),
( 6       ''        ''     'Elizabeth Allen'),
( 7       2         3      'Josiah II'),
( 8       2         3      'Susannah Wedgwood'),
( 9       5         4      'Robert Waring Darwin'),
( 10      7         6      'Josiah III'),
( 11      7         6      'Emma Wedgwood'),
( 12      9         8      'Charles Robert'),
( 13      9         8      'Caroline Sarah Darwin'),
( 14      10        13     'Margaret Wedgwood'),
( 15      11        12     'William Erasmus');
```

What I need is to gather the list of persons whose **SPOUSE** is also their **FIRST-DEGREE COUSIN**?

Can anyone help me with how to formulate the MySQL query?

Comment: This feels like homework... what have you tried?

Comment: Divide and conquer. Are you able to retrieve the spouse of one given person (technically speaking, the list of spouses ;). Are you able to retrieve the list of his first-degrees cousins?

Comment: Actually I don't get the exact logic on how to get the result. :/ I'm starting to learn mysql. Is this possible in executing multiple queries?

Comment: Am I missing something? How can you tell who's married to whom?

Comment: Treat each person as a child.. If you have the same father and mother = siblings..

Comment: I should also mention that in my country, it is not allowed to have several spouses, nor to marry his fist-degree counsin :D

Comment: How comes columns not null have null values?

Comment: I'm sorry.. It should have an empty data ( NOT null ).. And this is only an example :D

Comment: They should be nullable!

Comment: @Strawberry I suppose two persons could be considered married if they had a child. Again, this is disputable if you consider one can marry his cousin.

Comment: How old-fashioned - but I see where you're going...

Comment: What if Josiah had a mistress?

Comment: By then you have to return only those SPOUSES that happened to be also their FIRST-DEGREE COUSIN.

Comment: On the other hand, William Erasmus's father was Emma Wedgwood. So more progressive than we might have imagined.

Comment: This discussion is getting weird.

Comment: If you could teach me what is the algorithm in getting the desired result, would be of great help :D

Comment: @user2452111 The fact is it's complicated. Can I suggest you take a look at this example - it uses Shakespeare's family, but I think you can get the idea... [www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this question sounds so much like a homework, but I'm not someone who judges. I'm doing this as an exercise to my mind:

```
SELECT p1.father, p1.mother
FROM person p1
WHERE
    (p1.father, p1.mother) IN (
        SELECT firstSiblingChild.ID AS ID1, secondSiblingChild.ID AS ID2
        FROM (
            SELECT p1.ID AS ID1, p2.ID AS ID2
            FROM person p1
            INNER JOIN person p2 ON (p1.father = p2.father AND p1.mother = p2.mother)
            WHERE
                p1.father <> ""
            AND
                p1.mother <> ""
            AND
                p1.ID <> p2.ID
        ) siblings
        INNER JOIN person firstSiblingChild ON (siblings.ID1 = firstSiblingChild.father OR siblings.ID1 = firstSiblingChild.mother)
        INNER JOIN person secondSiblingChild ON (siblings.ID2 = secondSiblingChild.father OR siblings.ID2 = secondSiblingChild.mother)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your great idea, but this query returns: **Charles Robert, Caroline Sarah Darwin, Margaret Wedgwood, William Erasmus**. But based on my understanding, the correct records to be returned should be:
**Emma Wedgwood, Charles Robert, Josiah III, Caroline Sarah Darwin**.

Any suggestions/ comments regarding with my answer is of great help :)

Comment: I'm not sure how did you get `Charles Robert`, `Caroline Sarah Darwin`, `Margaret Wedgwood` and `William Erasmus`. This query returns `10,13` and `11,12` which means `Josiah III,Caroline Sarah Darwin` and `Emma Wedgwood,Charles Robert`, your exact expectations.

Comment: Anyways, your idea really helps! Thanks buddy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that people who have a child are married (and those with no child are not married) then possibly it can be done like this. But probably not that efficient.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.name
FROM (
SELECT a.ID AS Parent, c.ID AS GrandChild
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.father
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.father
UNION
SELECT  a.ID, c.ID
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.father
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.mother
UNION
SELECT  a.ID, c.ID
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.mother
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.mother
UNION
SELECT  a.ID, c.ID
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.mother
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.father) y
INNER JOIN (
SELECT a.ID AS Parent, c.ID AS GrandChild
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.father
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.father
UNION
SELECT  a.ID, c.ID
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.father
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.mother
UNION
SELECT  a.ID, c.ID
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.mother
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.mother
UNION
SELECT  a.ID, c.ID
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.mother
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.father) x
ON y.Parent = x.Parent
INNER JOIN person z ON z.father = x.GrandChild AND z.mother = y.GrandChild
INNER JOIN person f ON f.ID = z.father OR f.ID = z.mother
```

There are 2 large sub selects which each get a person and their grand children, joined together on the ID fields so they share the grandparent. These are then joined against the persons table, treating one subselect as the fathers and one as the mothers, to get any people whose parents share a grand parent, then that is joined against the person table again to get the actual parents.

EDIT - shorter code.

I have reduced the above so avoid the UNIONS by using OR in the ON clauses of the JOINs. I tend to hate using an OR in a JOIN but it does make it more readable.

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.name
FROM (
SELECT a.ID AS Parent, c.ID AS GrandChild
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.father OR a.ID = b.mother
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.father OR b.ID = c.mother
) y
INNER JOIN (
SELECT a.ID AS Parent, c.ID AS GrandChild
FROM person a
INNER JOIN person b ON a.ID = b.father OR a.ID = b.mother
INNER JOIN person c ON b.ID = c.father OR b.ID = c.mother
) x
ON y.Parent = x.Parent
INNER JOIN person z ON z.father = x.GrandChild AND z.mother = y.GrandChild
INNER JOIN person f ON f.ID = z.father OR f.ID = z.mother
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll be studying it so that I can comprehend it well.. Thanks for this great IDEA! :)